# Permission control in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

i have two registered  user's user **A** and **B**, user **A** can access user **B**'s post like edit.
how to prevent this. 
and sorry for my English.

```
    public function edit($id) 
    {

        $job_edit = job_posting::findOrFail($id);
        return view ('job.edit',compact('job_edit'));           
    }
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `posts` table should have a column `user_id`. Then in your logics part you need to check if this post belongs to particular user. It's difficult to advice without seeing the code but it may look something like this:

```
if($post->user_id != \Auth::user()->id)
{
    return Redirect::back()->with('error', "You can't edit somebody's else post.");
}
```

If you improve your question to be more concrete, we could help you better.

**UPDATE**:

Since you have added your code example, this should work:

Ok, so in your case it would be like this:

```
public function edit($id) 
{
    $job_edit = job_posting::findOrFail($id);

    if($job_edit->user_id != \Auth::user()->id)
    {
        return Redirect::back()->with('error', "You can't edit somebody's else post.");
    }

    return view ('job.edit',compact('job_edit'));           
}
```

Of course, you must have `user_id` field in your job_posting.